# 2d zooming and panning graphics screen in C++

Tags: c++, vector, graphics

Hi is there a preferred methodology for zoom and panning in a C/C++ program.
 Do you use vectors and matrices? If so how do I get started?

thanks

Comment: What graphics API are you planning to use?  C++ doesn't have any standard graphics libraries built in to the language, and different APIs work differently, so without knowing which 3rd-party API you will be using, this question will be impossible to answer.

Comment: Also what kind of App you writing? it is quite different for 2D/3D ... type of views etc...  For 2D I mostly use mouse wheel and center zooming around mouse cursor so you can also pan with zooming. right button is for pan (on mouse move/up/down event) left for selection (selection from left to right selects all inside, from right to left all inside and intersecting)  look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20924609/2521214

Comment: to implement zoom/pan you need add it to draw of all objects or to view transform matrix or to what ever you use so without more specifications is hard to answer ...

Comment: thanks.... I will be using Win API and it will be both 2d and 3d vector drawing app. I am familiar with WINapi and MFC mapping modes to implement zooming but I sort of wanted to make that part of the program platform independent in case I ever have to port it to Linux or something.