# Java Desktop GUI: Drag/Drop, Draw, insert background image

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, interactive

I have these requirements for a Desktop GUI program:

1. import image in the background
2. user should draw on top of it (lines, shapes)
3. should be able to click on drawn shapes and move them (mouse move).
   By clicking on points of drown lines, he should be able to move them
   (shape of the obj to be modified)
4. Should be able to drag and drop image to the ui (from let's say
   right-hand side panel)
5. I should be able to get coordinates of all drawn points by user

My question is what solution should I pick. I tried to use JApplet with graphics and 2, 3 and 5. I used simple Graphics and it looks ugly. I don't like it so I am here...

Does anyone have suggestions how to implement this. I can find bits and pieces online, but not an example which has ll this together.

Is there a better way to do what I am doing?

Isn't using JFrame a better and easier for this?

Comment: It's not clear whether you want a web GUI or a desktop GUI.  If you want a desktop GUI, you have the choice between Java Swing, JavaFX, or Apache Pivot.

Comment: I want a desktop GUI.

Comment: in case you want to code it yourself see mine [low level (no frameworks) example of a drag & drop in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20924609/2521214)