# How to manually get TMouseButton in C++Builder

Tags: c++builder

I am using C++Builder from Embarcadero Technology. The built in OnClick event handler does not identify if the mouse click is the left or right button. Is there a function I can call to manually fill the values for TMouseButton. Below is the OnClick event handler?

```
void __fastcall TForm::ListBox1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  TMouseButton Button;

  Button = ???
}
```

Comment: use evens that has `TShiftState Shift`  (OnMouseUp/Down/Move) and remember the `Shift` into your variable `Form1->sh` . Then if you need just use `if (Form1->sh.Contains(ssLeft)) ...` the buttons are `ssLeft,ssRight,ssMiddle` also some keys are handy `ssShift,ssAlt,ssCtrl` I usually also remember `x,y` position from `OnMouseMove` as I tend to use it a lot for stuff like selection focus switching/freeing etc. see [drag & drop C++/VCL example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450882/does-anyone-know-of-a-low-level-no-frameworks-example-of-a-drag-drop-re-ord/20924609?s=1|45.1559#20924609)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can use the `OnMouseDown` event to remember the current mouse button state for use in `OnClick`, eg.

```
private:
    bool LButtonDown;
    bool RButtonDown;

...

void __fastcall TForm1::ListBox1MouseDown(TObject *Sender, TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    switch (Button) {
        case mbLeft:
            LButtonDown = true;
            break;

        case mbRight:
            RButtonDown = true;
            break;
    }
}

void __fastcall TForm1::ListBox1MouseUp(TObject *Sender, TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    switch (Button) {
        case mbLeft:
            LButtonDown = false;
            break;

        case mbRight:
            RButtonDown = false;
            break;
    }
}

void __fastcall TForm::ListBox1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (LButtonDown) ...
    if (RButtonDown) ...
}
```

If you don't want to do that way, you can use the Win32 API [`GetKeyState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate) or [`GetAsyncKeyState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) function to query the current state of the mouse's left and right buttons, using the `VK_LBUTTON` and `VK_RBUTTON` virtual key codes, eg:

```
void __fastcall TForm::ListBox1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)) ...
    if (GetKeyState(VK_RBUTTON)) ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct event to use for details of mouse click events is `OnMouseDown` (also `OnMouseUp` and `OnMouseMove`).

Override the event and then implement MouseDown event like this

```
void __fastcall TMyListView::MouseDown(System::Uitypes::TMouseButton Button, System::Classes::TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
     if (Button == mbLeft){

     }
     if (Button == mbRight){

     }
}
```

See also [Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnMouseDown](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnMouseDown) in Embarcadero's documentation.